# Bash: Reading from array

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'm writing a script in bash, and I'm trying to read from an array. When I iterate through the array with the code below:

```
for item in "${!functionDict[@]}"
do
    echo "{ $item : ${functionDict[$item]} }" >> array.txt
done
```

it outputs (in "array.txt"):

```
{  month_start_date($year_selected, $month_selected) : return $date; }
{  logWarning($message) : return logEvent($message, $c_event_warning); }
{  daysPastLastQuarterX($curYear, $curMonth, $curDay, $selected_year, $selected_quarter,   $nDays) : return false;:return false;:return false;:return false;:return true;:return $delta > $nDays; }
{  setExcelLabelCell($sheet, $cell, $label, $width) :  }
{  asCurrencyString($value) : return formatCurrency($value); }
{  getNumericMonthName($m) : return $numericMonth; }
{  normalize_for_PDF(&$text) :  }
```

However, I'm having trouble querying individual elements from the array.

**I've tried**:

```
string='month_start_date($year_selected, $month_selected)'
echo "test_output: ${functionDict[$string]}"
```

**but I get**

```
test_output: <blank>
```

**I've also tried inserting some RegEx wildcards, in case there is some whitespace around the key.**

```
echo 'size of array: '"${#functionDict[@]}"
echo "TEST: functDict[logWarning] = ${functionDict[.*'logWarning($message)'.*]}"
```

**I get**

```
size of array: 157   //I didn't copy/paste all the elements in the array in this post
TEST: functDict[logWarning] = <blank>
```

Alas, I'm stuck. The content that I'm trying to get back are the "return **_**" items, or just a "blank" for the keys that don't have any "return" items.

Comment: what if you try with `string=' month_start_date($year_selected, $month_selected)'` (with a space in front of `month_start_date`)? it seems you have a leading space in your keys...

Comment: It is working here: http://ideone.com/zynNIv

Comment: @perreal: of course it works for you, you don't have the leading space in your keys.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf, think you are right, there must be a space

Comment: AHHHHHH. Thank you so much @gniourf_gniourf!!!! It was that little space in front!! I didn't realize there were TWO leading spaces in the output. Everything works lovely now. :D

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Have a new screen name for you … **hawk_eyes**

Answer (score 0):

Credits to answer goes to @gniourf_gniourf. (See comments)

There was an extra leading space in all of the keys, which I hadn't included in my test queries.

(Providing an answer here so that people know this question has been solved. Hopefully this is okay practice on SO)